# xmppframework disco items filtering

Tags: ios, swift, ejabberd, xmppframework

is there any way whereby I can query for example a list of muc rooms but specify certain constraints.

I have attached the location of each room in each room's configuration form under the description field. I want to find out what is the best way to get all the rooms within 500m of the user's location.

On the backend, I have ejabberd server. It will be great if anyone can point me to the right documentation for this particular example

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in Multi-User Chat extension (XEP-0045) and as such ejabberd does not implement anything special.

To implement your business logic, you will need to write a custom ejabberd module that find the room for your user based on your location criteria and return the result.